# setListImg is not accepting the blob values

Tags: javascript, forms, web, frontend, blob

Well, in my second useEffect I'm trying to pass the value of imgFiles to listImg, but my code doesn't update immediately and with that the list is empty, even though I have a value in imgFiles resulting in the error "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' in 'URL ': Overload resolution failed.
"
Does anyone know what I can do to avoid this?

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (listFunc.length !== 0) {
            let urls
            const imgfetch = async () => {
                const imgFiles = await Promise.all(
                    listFunc.map(async (fun) => {
                        console.log('funcionarios:',listFunc)
                        console.log(`${fun.nome} codigo ${fun.cod}`)
                        let resp = await fetch(url + `imagem/${fun.cod}-func`, { method: 'GET' })
                        let resposta = await resp.blob()
                        return resposta

                    }))
                setListImg(imgFiles)//doesn't put the value inside listImg
                
                
            }
            imgfetch();
            setStatus('ocioso')
        }

    }, [listFunc])

...

return (
        <div>
            {listFunc.map((fun) => {
                const url =URL.createObjectURL(listImg[fun.cod-1])//where the error happens
                return (
                    <div style={{ textAlign: "justify", padding: '20px 100px 0px 100px' }} key={fun.cod}>

                        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                            <img src={url}></img>
                            <div style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }}>
                                <h2>{fun['nome']}</h2>
                                <p>{fun.desc}</p><br />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            {/*user.nome!==''?<button style={{height:'30px',margin:'50px'}}>algo</button>:null*/}

                        </div>

                        <hr></hr>

                    </div>
                )
            })}
            {/*user.nome!==''?<button>algo2</button>:null*/}
        </div>
    );
```

I tried the code above, but the listImg continue empty [], even through the imgFiles has the blob values.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code?

Comment: Also, how and where exactly do you check that "the imgFiles has the blob values"?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code

- First of all map doesn't work with async callbacks
- Promise.all receive an array of promises not array of results

In order to work with this before Promise.all, map all functions and return the fetch call or block depends what you prefer (without the await), then pass the returned values (array of promises) to Promise.all then work as normal async function (after awaiting Promise.all)